# jquery mobile flipswitch active by default

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm using query mobile 1.4.0 and I'm trying to make my flip switch active by default but I'm not really sure how to approach it. I've tried adding `selected="selected"` to the `<input>` but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Anyone have any ideas?

```
      <form>
      <div class="prof-wrap">
        <div class="prof-left">
          <div class="prof-txt-wrap">
            <div class="text-off">OFF TITLE</div>
            <div class="text-off2">OFF TYPE</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END prof-left -->
        <div class="prof-mid">
          <div class="prof-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-4" id="flip-checkbox-4" data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch" selected="selected">
          </div>
          <!--END prof-mid --> 
        </div>
        <!-- END prof-switch -->
        <div class="prof-right">
          <div class="prof-txt-wrap2">
            <div class="text-active">ON TITLE</div>
            <div class="text-active2">ON TYPE</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END prof-right --> 
      </div>
      <!-- END prof-wrap -->
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/flipswitch/) use the `checked=""`attribute:

```
<form>
    <label for="flip-checkbox-4">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-4" id="flip-checkbox-4" checked="">
</form>
```